# Remove tracking pixels and similar stuff from HTML

Tags: security, html-parsing, privacy, tracking-pixel

Our application is heavily based on email (it's a helpdesk ticketing system) and I'd like to protect our users and block 3rd party tracking from incoming messages HTML (mainly tracking pixels).

We're already doing HTML/DOM parsing (to "sanitize" dangerous and unwanted tags), so HTML-parsing is not really a technical challenge. The challenge is **how to detect 3rd party trackers?** Are there any common characteristics we could use?

Currently I came up with 2 approaches:

1. Use a set of rules like:

   - `img` has external `src`
   - `src` with query-parameters
   - low dimensions (0 or 1 pixel width/height)
2. Simply use an existing filter list (uBlock Origin, for example, publishes their lists [here](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/tree/master/filters)) and remove all tags pointing to dangerous destinations

Any other ideas that I'm missing? Would love to hear some input from someone who's dealt with this before.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's about all you can do, though blocking all external resources would be safer - there's no definitive link between image size and tracking, though it is a common pattern.

There are lists of known trackers [here](https://github.com/mozilla-services/shavar-prod-lists) ad [here](https://github.com/disconnectme/disconnect-tracking-protection). Hey.com may also have some resources to help block trackers.